# Cannot DELETE /api/users/IDHERE error in postman Express Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Hi everyone I can neither delete nor update any use. When i try so i get Cannot DELETE /api/users/60880b17e6e874251067931c on postman but this error doesn't show on console. This is happening despite having that ID on the mongodb compass

mongodb compas
[image]

postman
[image]

The routes

```
router.put(':/id', async (req, res) => {
const {error} = validate(req.body)
if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)

const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    $set : {
        username : req.body.username,
        bio : req.body.bio,
        images : req.body.images,
        email : req.body.email,
        phone : req.body.phone,
        bodyType : req.body.bodyType,
        age : req.body.age,
        serviceTypes : req.body.serviceTypes,
        isPremium : req.body.isPremium,
        isAdmin : req.body.isAdmin,
        location : req.body.location,
        password : req.body.password
    }
})

try {
    if (!user) return res.status(404).send('That user does not exists')


       res.send(user)
        console.log(user)
    }
    catch (exp) {
        console.log(exp)
    }
})

// delete request
router.delete(':/id', async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id)
    if (!user) return res.status(404).send('That user does not exists')
    res.send(user)
})
```

Comment: I saw my error I wrote ":/id" instead of "/:id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put '/' before the semicolon on put route path